# Form result & Entity Framework has different Input names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, entity-framework, razor

I am using EF6 with my project. I had to return a class containing two separate classes to my view. Sorry for the use of non generic names and use of jargon class names

The model returned to my is as follows:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public List<ProductEntity> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public PricingConfigurationLog PricingConfiguration { get; set; }
}
```

Here is an example of the an input using Razor Syntax for a form field.

**Razor Syntax**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PricingConfiguration.PromoText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

**HTML output**

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="PricingConfiguration_PromoText" name="PricingConfiguration.PromoText" type="text" value="Promotional Text">
```

When passing the form elements back into my controller to process them for the EntityFramework to update/insert to the database the columns are empty.

This seems to be evident of the elements form name being rendered as `name="PricingConfiguration.PromoText` and not `PromoText`

This is where I don't know how to change the rendering or the Binding below.

```
public ActionResult SaveConfiguration([Bind(Include =  "ProductCode,"
                                                     + "PromoText,"
                                                     + "CartLimitPerDay,"
                                                     + "CartDayAllowed,"
                                                     + "SessionDeleteTimeMinutes,"
                                                     + "SessionTimeoutMinutes")] PricingConfigurationLog PricingConfigurationLog)
```

Comment: It looks like you figured out one way to "skin this cat".  However, as a suggestion I would recommend using view models and not entities.  More importantly I would suggest you try and flatten your view models as much as possible.  It isn't always possible but it eliminates the types of headaches you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Binding to Prefix each field with PricingConfiguration

```
public ActionResult SaveConfiguration([Bind(Prefix="PricingConfiguration")] PricingConfigurationLog PricingConfigurationLog)
```